# Mongo dump and restore to a different cluster and I cannot log in

Tags: mongodb, express, bcrypt, mongodb-atlas

I moved a mongoDB from one atlas cluster to a different account/different cluster.

To do this I did a dump from the source db and a restore to the new account's cluster.

I did NOT have a problem restoring the db - that went fine - I can visually confirm that the hashes in the new db ARE the same as the old.

When I try to login to my app (pointed to the source) I get in fine, when I change my db setting and point to the new db I get a log in failed.

The api code is the same - running locally, the only thing that is different is the connection string.

I am using bcrypt to hash the passwords - but because the api is sitting on my local machine, that kind of takes any application layer variable out of my problem list.

With the exception of the connection string - I was using the 3.1 driver connection string to connect to the 'old' version, and I decided to try the 3.6 driver version to connect to the 'new'.

Can someone confirm that moving a db from one cluster to another, using the dump and restore method SHOULD not effect hashed password matching.??

And maybe offer suggestions on where to look for answers?

so the only difference on the code is this:

```
// Old
DB_URI=mongodb://u***:p***@dev0-shard-00-00-1xxx.mongodb.net:27017,dev0-shard-00-01-1xxx.mongodb.net:27017,dev0-shard-00-02-1xxx.mongodb.net:27017/db?ssl=true&replicaSet=Dev0-shard-0&authSource=admin


// new
DB_URI=mongodb+srv://n***:h***@prod-xxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

Comment: Divide and conquer. `console.log` raw data your script retrieves from old and new db. If it is the same the problem is elsewhere, may be different version of bcrypt/libssl. If it differs - check data manually to confirm export-import was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I finally got around to playing with stuff, and since the URI was the only change, I switched back to the 3.4 driver syntax (that long ungodly string), and it works fine.

For the record, all my "open" (non-authenticated) API calls, such as with signup, or requesting a forgotten password. and a slew of drop down lookup, all processed thru the api with the 3.6 driver, I also signed up and logged in fine - the only issue is logging in with an account that was created in the previous cluster, with the new driver connection string.

And as confirmation - now that I switched the connection string back to 3.4 - I cannot log into the account I created with the 3.6 connection string.